# How to do OAuth dance with Deezer API on iOS?

Tags: ios, api, swiftui, oauth, deezer

I'm currently trying to complete the OAuth dance with the [Deezer API](https://developers.deezer.com/api/oauth).
I have created a Deezer app on their site and full fill required fields.
I'm not using the Deezer SDK as it's deprecated since a long time ago.
I'm loading the request with a `WKWebView` and the request looks like :
`https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php?app_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URL&response_type=token&perms=basic_access`

This open a webview displaying an auth form.
After i login with my deezer account credentials, i'm supposed to be redirected to the previous specified url `MY_REDIRECT_URL`.
But i intercept the redirection like this :

```
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void) {
        if !isLoading {
            isLoading = true
        }
        if let redirectedUrl = navigationAction.request.url, redirectedUrl.host == AppConfig.redirectHost {
            // extracting token from url
            let deezerToken = DeezerURLBuilder.deezerToken(fromUrl: redirectedUrl)
            // saving token
            PrefUtils.shared.deezerToken = deezerToken
            didLogin = true
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

I don't want to go to the redirect url because i'm in a iOS app and i hope i could prevent the server step.

I have noticed that the `redirectedUrl` looks like : `https://MY_REDIRECT_URL/#access_token=frazeeFRT188maXzvPiCeTDEjCCbrIGGaCwlkGQra4whmp7rtJ&expires=1468`

I don't understand why because from the Deezer API, i should see a `code` query parameter which i should put in the next request for App Authentication like this :
`https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/access_token.php?app_id=MY_APP_ID&secret=MY_APP_SECRET&code=THE_MISSING_CODE`
That request was sent with `URLSession.shared.data`.

So i was assuming that i got the final access_token and continue to request the user info with :
`https://api.deezer.com/user/me?access_token=frazeeFRT188maXzvPiCeTDEjCCbrIGGaCwlkGQra4whmp7rtJ`

Finally i got an error stating : "*An active token must be used to query information about the current user*"

I try the first request inside Safari in macOS then i was redirected to `MY_REDIRECT_URL`. After this i tried the request to get user info and it succeeded, i saw the json response in the Safari.

As i understand, Deezer has set cookies during the redirection in Safari. My guess is requests are completed because of the cookies and when i'm in the iOS App `WKWebView` is dismiss and subsequent requests are made without these.

To sum up,
<s>why am i getting `access_token` without providing 'my app secret request' ?</s>
*(because i ask for it with the `response_type` param set to `token`)*

How to properly do OAuth dance with Deezer API in SwiftUI/Swift App without Deezer SDK ?

PS: I didn't try [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift) library as i want to keep it simple.

Thx for any help

**EDIT: SOLVED**

it was a typo in my url parameter... but it is fully working without a server redirect.

Comment: You should use [`ASWebAuthenticationSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession), not a web view. This makes it much easier to handle the redirection. Your redirection url will need to be an "app url scheme", not a https: url (ie something like "MyAppAuth://")

Comment: And you will probably find it much simpler to use an existing library than to create your own OAuth handling.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i already tried the ASWebAuthenticationSession, the problem is that the redirection url must be a valid url (i mean with https scheme) because if not Deezer API will complain with "You must provide a valid url" kind of error

Comment: If that is the case then you will not be able to use their authentication directly from a mobile app.  You will need to create your own server to proxy the request.  If their implementation only accepts https redirect values you need a server to accept that and then issue a redirect back to your app.

Comment: but as i understand, what's happening actually is that i have the access_token. So why can't i have a valid response  instead of this error ? Why my token isn't active when i call from the iOS App ?